# Does HTML5 sessionStorage exist on the server or client?

Tags: html

I was at an HTML5 presentation at MSFT yesterday and they indicated that HTML5 sessionStorage is stored on the server and localStorage was stored on the client.  Can someone clarify if sessionStorage is persisted during its use on the browser or it is on the server? If it is stored on the server, what mechanism is used to persist it?

If it is stored on the server, it seems to me that each reference to sessionStorage data on the client would cause network traffic.  If it is stored on the client, is it available if the device is offline (say due to a dropped connection)?

I am wondering if the difference between sessionStorage and localStorage is just semantic with both being stored locally and just having different lifetimes on the data that is stored within them, with localStorage being used to persist data that needs to exist past the lifetime of the browser instance.

Answer (score 3):

Local Storage and Session storage are both stored on the client. The difference is that Session storage is tied to the life of the session and Local Storage is stored indefinitely.