# Session doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session

So, I'm trying to make a web application. During registration, I require from the user to enter his working experience. While at it, I test if the time span in which the user has been working overlaps with previously entered time spans, just to warn him of it. I use controller and JS script for this.

This is my controller method:

```
public void TimeCheck()
    {
        string time = Request.QueryString.ToString();

        using (ITExpertsContext db = new ITExpertsContext())
        {
            int id = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).UserId;

            List<WorkingAt> currentHistory = db.WorkingAts.Where(x => x.UserId == id).ToList();

            TimeFrame frame = new TimeFrame();

            frame.Since = DateTime.Parse(time.Split('&')[0].Split('=')[1]);
            frame.Until = DateTime.Parse(time.Split('&')[1].Split('=')[1]);

            foreach (WorkingAt w in currentHistory)
            {
                if ((w.Since < frame.Until && w.Until > frame.Until) || (w.Since < frame.Since && w.Until > frame.Since))
                {
                    Session["Time"] = "1";
                    return;
                }
            }

            Session["Time"] = "0";
        }
    }
```

And this is my JS method from the view:

```
function TimeCheck() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open("GET", "/account/TimeCheck/?since=" + $("#Since").val() + "&until=" + $("#Until").val());

            request.send();

            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.status == 200 & request.readyState == 4) {
                    if (sessionStorage.Time == "1") {
                        var choice = confirm("The time you selected overlaps with your previous working experience. Do you still want to add it?");
                        if (choice == true) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem with all of this is my session does not change at all, aka does not exist. It works well when I set it from JS (for testing purpose). What am I doing wrong?

I'm using latest VS 2017 ver 15.7, so I'm assuming my MVC is 5.2.3, if that's even needed to be known.

EDIT:
The code in controller reaches to the end without any problems. I did the debug of controller line by line and it works as I designed it. Just before "return" I tried reading session["Time"] and it shows it's there. Once the execution goes back to the JS the browser does not show there's a session data under the key "Time", and therefore my "if(sessionStorage.Time == "1")" statement is pointless.

Comment: too many unknowns here regarding any debugging you have done and how you use this client side. Also `return` inside `onreadystatechange` is suspicious since there is nowhere to return to. Start by showing how you use this client side and by doing some basic debugging to determine if problem is client side or server side

Comment: Also since you are using jQuery already should consider using `$.ajax` instead of creating your own `XMLHttpRequest` so you can take advantage of it's error handling

Comment: My problem is not with the script, but with the fact I can't set the session from my controller, and I should be able to do that.

Comment: Why not return a json object? This doesn't need session at all

Comment: Because this is not a project, but a practice. I know I can use json object as a return type, but I want to know why the session part doesn't work, and it should be. What am I doing wrong in this example?

Comment: Because sessionStorage is client side only I believe. You get and set it on the client, it won't come down from the server.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205167/does-html5-sessionstorage-exist-on-the-server-or-client

Comment: @sheavens So, there are two sessions, one for the client and one for the server. It makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sessionStorage is defined in the HTML5 spec. which is client side only, so setting a Session variable on the server has no effect on sessionStorage client side.
See: [Does HTML5 sessionStorage exist on the server or client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205167/does-html5-sessionstorage-exist-on-the-server-or-client)